# nodejs - req.body returns undefined when sent to be handled in anther file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working on a project involving nodejs and I'm having a problem with a request body that is undefined

On the client side I fetch some data

I also get the following error telling me the property is undefined or null

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property `email` of 'undefined' or 'null'.

Anyone know what might cause this and how I can fix this, all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting the error on the client or the server?

Comment: I get the error on the server side

Comment: You pass only one argument/object to `signup(...)` -> `req.body`. Why are you trying to access `req` & `res`? `req` is in your "signup" function = `req.body`

Comment: @kapa424 The problem was JSON.stringifty sends a string. That's why you couldn't destructure property email since you can't do that with a string, that's a JSON implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `body: JSON.stringify(userData),` to `body: userData`
Add `app.use(express.json()` above `app.post` so you can work with the json. req.body should have an email property on the server when fetching now. Your function signup takes 2 arguments, (req, res) instead of (req.body) BTW.

```
const userData = {
    username,
    email,
    password
};

fetch(API_URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: userData,
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
});
```

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const { signup, login } = require ('./authController');

app.use(express.json())

app.post('/signup', signup)
```

```
const { createUser, findUserByEmail } = require('./user');
const { comparePassword, createToken } = require('./auth');

// Controller function to handle a signup request
async function signup(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
  try {
   
  } catch (error) {
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here 's fixing

```
const userData = {
username:'deathstar',
email:'jjjrr@gamil.com',
password:'ssss'
```

};

```
fetch(API_URL, {
method: 'POST',
body: JSON.stringify(userData),
headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
}
```

});

this is back-end code too

```
 const express = require('express');
  const cors = require('cors');
  
  const fs = require('fs');
   const path = require('path');
   const app = express();

   const port = 5500;

   app.use(cors()); // enable CORS

  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

   app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

   app.get('/',(req,res)=>{

 res.sendFile('index.html');
  });

  app.post('/signup', (req, res) =>{
   console.log(req.body);

      }); 

     app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Comment: That isn't different from my code other than you have made the userdata static, I already get the userdata from a form so that wouldn't help me

Comment: i test your code and work fine one my pc

Comment: i update answer add back-end code too